# Email address domain validation does not take place using bootstrapValidator

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Email Address:***

Validation happens till abc@abc
Domain validation is not taking place.What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Basically twitter-bootstrap internally uses html5 email validator and domain validation is not available in html5

so you need the regex pattern validation and recommended regex is 
`ng-pattern = '/^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$`/i'

Comment: Did not work with this.It was showing success at abc@abc Added this code in js and it worked.$('#basicBootstrapForm').bootstrapValidator({
  feedbackIcons: {
    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
  },
  fields: {
    email: {
      validators: {
        notEmpty: {
          message: 'The email address is required'
        },
        regexp: {
          regexp: '^[^@\\s]+@([^@\\s]+\\.)+[^@\\s]+$',
          message: 'The value is not a valid email address'
        }
      }
    },
  }
});

Comment: If this is helpful to you please upvote and accept my answer